# Beaglebone: usb0 interface not showing up

Tags: networking, usb, ssh, beagleboard

I recently installed Ubuntu 14 on my BeagleBone from [armhf.com](http://www.armhf.com/boards/beaglebone-black/). However, I'm unable to `ssh` into my Beaglebone over USB. Running `ifconfig`, I discovered that there is the usb0 interface is not showing up. Is this an issue with the image of Ubuntu that I installed or is this some configuration problem with my host machine.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on my host PC

Comment: Is there an interface listed that starts with 'em' or something like p5p1?

Comment: no. ifconfig only lists `eth0` `wlan0` and `lo` as the interfaces

Comment: eth0 is the default network interface normally, are you expecting usb0 because you're using a usb network card or something?

Comment: No. I'm trying to connect to the beaglebone via the USB cable (no network card). Before installing this image, the beaglebone always showed an interface as `usb0`

Comment: Have you tried `ifup usb0`? This should bring up the interface if it exists, or at least give you some sort of error message.

Comment: Same issue I am facing now. Any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `auto usb0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` did the job for me.